# How to deactive colorcolumn quickly in different situation?

Tags: colorcolumn

I have read the manual in vim with `:h cc` or `h: 'cc'`, but I found nothing about how to remove the red lines.

**First use case**

I create the red line with this command:

```
:set cc=1,5,9,13,17,21
```

With the following command I can disable `cc` ,or to remove all the red lines created by the previous command:

```
:set cc-=1,5,9,13,17,21  "Use minus `-` to remove all the red lines here.
```

Is there a more quickly way to remove all the red lines?

**Use case 2**

I create the red line with this command:

```
:exec "set cc=".join(range(1,21,4),",")
```

How to deactive cc command in this case?

[image]

Comment: I.e. read the picture text *ad litteram* :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can clear all the lines by just setting `cc` to an empty value like so:

```
:set cc=
```

You also can create a command or mapping to toggle between the two, `&cc` refers to the `cc` setting, we need to use `let` since we want to use an expression:

```
command! ToggleCC :let &cc = &cc == '' ? '1,4,21' : ''

nnoremap <F2> :let &cc = &cc == '' ? '1,4,21' : ''<CR>
```

If `&cc` is empty, we set it to `1,4,21`, if it has a value, we set it to nothing.

This is really a shorter version of the longer:

```
fun! ToggleCC()
  if &cc == ''
    set cc=1,4,21
  else
    set cc=
  endif
endfun

nnoremap <F2> :call ToggleCC()<CR>
```